# How can I determine, inside of the template, whether or not an image was uploaded?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I'm trying to determine if a user has uploaded an image after submitting data via a form.

Let's say I have a model:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    cover_image = models.ImageField(upload_to="foo/bar/fun")
```

The cover image is not required, so this object can be created without a `cover_image` value.

Now, in a template, I want to check to see if there was an uploaded file. If there is no uploaded file, a default chunk of HTML should be displayed. My initial approach doesn't seem to work, and I'm stuck. **For some reason, the image area shows as if there's an image to display when there isn't; the alt text is, therefore, displayed instead. What should actually be displayed is a different chunk of HTML, like so**:

```
{% if my_book_context_object.cover_image %}
<img src="the image"></img>
{% else %}
<img src="placeholder image"></img>
{% endif %}
```

I was considering that I might check inside of a model method, but I'm not really sure of what to check for:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    cover_image = models.ImageField(upload_to="foo/bar/fun")

    def has_cover_image(self):
        ...unknown check logic...
        return True or False
```

Comment: You can check like this: `bool(self.cover_image)`

Comment: @FatihErikli That didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

No need to check if you have a image, I guess.

You can default a Image in your model. Default is, if nobody uploads a Image there will be a default image to be displayed. When you 'upload' the route is changed.

```
class Book(models.Model):
    cover_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='foo/bar/fun', default='foo/bar/fun/taco.jpg')
```

Acording to me, your code must work, I dont know why is not. 
You shuold write what error are you getting.

Comment: But I don't want there to be a default image. A user **does not** need to upload an image with their post. There should be no default.

Comment: I dont get it. If the user dont upload an image, there will be a default image anyway.

Comment: Assume that a user doesn't want an image attached to their post. I need to check for that condition.

Comment: What kind of issue are you having with that code? Can you be more specific?

Comment: I've edited the initial post. Hopefully I've cleared things up. If not, let me know.

Comment: Im assuming that your code get in `{% if my_book_context_object.cover_image %}`

Comment: Maybe the source of `<img src="the image"></img>` is wrong. Is a common mistake that the beginning of the url has something extra like 'cover/'.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74143/discussion-between-larachicharo-and-mr-spock).